# how to auto load javascript after iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

i have iframe embed code of youtube video and i want to auto load javascript after each iframe. i using wordpress.

I want to create this - when the user open any post/page in my wordpress website, if the post/page contain any iframe then javascript auto load after each iframe.

this is javascript which i want to load after iframe.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script>
function onYtEvent(payload) {
if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
  // Add code to handle subscribe event.
} else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
  // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
}
if (window.console) { // for debugging only
  window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
}
}
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC_Lmg76m-DMN_EVURz_G9zw" data-layout="full" data-count="hidden" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

this is iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blablabla" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[i wanna create like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoYu6.png)

Answer (score 0):

use the onload function for auto loading the javascript

```
<iframe onload="onYtevent();" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blablabla"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.load()` jquery function.

It's fired after iframe has been loaded.

That's code:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
   // here your code
});
```